# Custom binding that passes specific context to children?

Tags: knockout.js

I've created a custom binding in Knockout, that I use to generate a window and set defaults.

The window makes an ajax call to go retrieve a template which it will use as its content.

**Is there a way I can make sure this content gets bound?**

i.e Once the template is loaded into the page, I want any knockout bindings within the template to render/process.

**Along with that, is there a way that I can set what the context of the bindings for the content will be?**

i.e From my custom binding I would like to say that my 'value.contentOptions' object is the starting level for the content that gets loaded into the window.

I feel its some combination of **ko.applyBindingsToDescendants**, **bindingContext.createChildContext**, **ko.applyBindingsToNode** and **controlsDescendantBindings** but i'm afraid I cant seem to figure it out

I would post code but at this point its just sheer guessing D: - If you would like to see some of my binding code let me know.

Some caveats I see with what i'm trying to do:

Content isn't loaded until most likely after the binding has finished since its async and may have to go to the server.

My custom binding is a wrapper for a Kendo Window, and i'm trying to use its built in 'content' feature <- I do not have to use this feature, though I would like to keep the window if I can at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the second parameter when calling applyBindings.  The first parameter, which is required, is the viewmodel.  The second parameter, which is optional, is the DOM element where the bindings should be applied (default is the entire page).

Here is an example:

```
<div id="templateGoesHere"></div>
<div id="otherPart">
    <div data-bind="text: otherStuff"></div>
</div>​
```

And the corresponding javascript:

```
var vm = {
    messages : {
        myMessage : ko.observable("Hello World!")
    },
    otherStuff : ko.observable("Nothing to see here")
};

// Apply bindings to the part of the page that doesn't
// include where the template will go
ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#otherPart')[0]);

// Get template from elsewhere
var template = "<span data-bind='text: myMessage'></span>";
// Add template to page
$('#templateGoesHere').html(template);
// Bind data to template
ko.applyBindings(vm.messages, $('#templateGoesHere')[0]);
​
```

You have have a div (templateGoesHere) where you insert your template, and after your template is added to the page, you call applyBindings, telling knockout to apply the bindings only to your template.

Additionally, when you apply bindings, you can specify that you only want a part of the viewmodel (vm.messages) to be used for the bindings instead of the entire viewmodel.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Hvxn/

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I've done why my combobox binding (Its a unfished combobox for knockout)

I use a custom template source (Instead of the build in one that uses script tags) and then ko.renderTemplate together with constrol descents true, please see my answer here

[Add Knockout Data Driven Table to Knockout Data Driven Accordion Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972436/add-knockout-data-driven-table-to-knockout-data-driven-accordion-pane/13973473#13973473)

edit: About loading the async ajax template, at init you can bind to a empty dummy templta and then when the actual template is loaded bind to that, just make sure you bind the template name to a observable